# Is my calcualtion from the mass of a photon right?

Tags: photons, mass

The Mass off a Photon

The right format can be found here: [Photon](http://gsjournal.net/Science-Journals/Communications-Quantum%20Theory%20/%20Particle%20Physics/Download/3814)

E = hv
E = mc2
E = av (amplitude, frequency)
m = hv/c2 Mass = movement of electromagnetic fields
Planck’s constant = electromagnetic amplitude!
a = E /v <=> h = E/v
Basic Formula’s for Circular Movement with Speed C
v =1/T
v(speed) = c = 2πr/T (1)= 2πvr
amplitude = a = ω = 2π/T = 2πv
T = 2π/a (2)
From 1 and 2
c = 2πr/2π/a
=> c = ra
Calculation r
Because a = h
r = c/h
r = 3x108
/6.62x10-34
= 0.45x1042
Calculation T
T = 2π/h
= 6.28/6.62x10-34
= 0.9486x1034 Calculation Mass Photon
2 formula’s
m = hv/c2
v = c/2πr
m = h/2πrc (1 formula)
= 6.62x10-34
/6.28x0.45x1042x3x108
= 0.775x 10-84 = Mass Photon
m = hv/c2
v = h/2π
=> m = h2 /2πc
2 (2 formula)
= 6.622
x10- 68/2x3.14x32 x1016
= 0.775x 10-84 = Mass Photon
Proof 3 theorem Bohr + dualistic character for photons
2πr = nλ (1)
2π = hT (2)
v (speed) = c = hr = 2πvr = λ/T(3)
h = mc
2
/v (c/v = λ)
=> h = mλc
=> λ = h/mc
Conclusion:
2πr = nh/mc

The right format can be found here: [Photon](http://gsjournal.net/Science-Journals/Communications-Quantum%20Theory%20/%20Particle%20Physics/Download/3814)

Conclusions:
1. Photons have a mass
2. A photon is the most elementary particle that excists
3. The mass of a photon is the most elementary in nature
4. The influence of gravitation and electromagnetic fields is finite
5. A photon proofs the third theorem of Bohr
6. Because a photon is an elementary field and mass is nothing else then this, we get the
proof of the dualistic character (the Broglie!)
7. Energy = vibration width mass
8. Mass = frequency of movement

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no, your calculation does not seem to be correct.

Your calculation is based on Einsteins famous equation $E=mc^2$; however, this equation is actually only valid for *objects at rest*, while all experiments confirm that photons in a vacuum move with a constant speed of $2.99...\times10^8$~m/s.

The equation Einstein gave for *moving particles* is the following, where $p$ is the momentum of the particle:
$$ E = \sqrt{m^2c^4 + p^2c^2} $$
You can easily verify that setting $p=0$, which is true for a stationary object, gives you back the equation $E=mc^2$. If you instead use the relationship $E=pc$ between the energy and momentum of a photon, which is consistent with measurements of radiation pressure, then the above equation gives you $m=0$, i.e. the photon mass is zero.